# How does a photonic tensor core work?

Tags: photons, computer

There has been much media coverage of the paper [Photonic Tensor Cores for Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2002/2002.03780.pdf):

- https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/ai-machine-learning-light-speed-artificial-intelligence-a9629976.html
- https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/07/200721114731.htm
- https://techxplore.com/news/2020-07-photon-based-enable-complex-machine.html

However, neither the paper nor the media coverage seem to actually explain how such a "Photonic TPU" actually works. Maybe I have been living under a rock, but I have never heard of a matrix processor which works using photons instead of the classical electrical circuits.

There have been [neural networks implemented with photons instead of electrical circuits](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/07/neural-network-implemented-with-light-instead-of-electrons/), but these approaches are limited to the evaluation of a pre-trained NN, whereas a "Photonic TPU" would be able to actually train a network.

What is the concept behind Photonic TPUs, how do they work?

Answer (score 1):

The news coverage dont explain. It is clear from the paper. There are multiple units that perform the dot-product operation, using Wavelength division multiplexing. These wavelengths, which represent the entries of a 4x1 vector (modulated carriers), are weighted through multi-bit photonic memories that are written electrically. The weighted wavelengths are summed together by photodetector. And this happens for all the 16 dot-products of a 4x4 matrix-matrix multiplication. very similar to electronic TPU operations, with difference that most operations are performed while photons travel in the waveguides. It is elegant. no separation between memory and processing.

Answer (score 0):

What Anelov says seems correct. https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/07/neural-network-implemented-with-light-instead-of-electrons/ reads as a diffractive optics network with 3d printed "boards". It can not be tuned. You need to 3d print new modules for new neural networks. The photonic tensor core uses micron size waveguides, so much smaller and it seems that the memory can be written and it can potentially implement multiple neural networks.

Comment: No, your link is about the pre-trained neural network which has been implemented optically. There is a link in the question, and I explicitly said that the question is about *neural network training* with photons instead of currents, not just NN evaluation.